# Make a list of 50 random numbers in the range 1-50, such that adjacent numbers are not within 15 of each other

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

This is what I have so far but it breaks if I go past plus or minus 11 the previous number. So if the previous number is 1 the next number has to be more than 16. Also I am trying to only use each number once.

Example output:

```
[3,45, 1, 16, 33, 3, 23.....]
```

My script so far is:

```
import random
new_array=[]
counter = 0

array=range(51)
array=array[1:51]

while len(new_array)<50:
    y=random.choice(array)
    if y not in new_array and counter!=0 and y not in (range(new_array[counter-1]-11,new_array[counter-1]+11)):
        new_array.append(y)
        counter+=1
    elif counter == 0:
        new_array.append(y)
        counter+=1
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Hint: Instead of playing with `range()`, just subtract the two numbers.

Comment: The fun issue with your algorithm is its execution time is not bounded. It may take 42 years to execute if you're unlucky.

Comment: The problem is actually much more complex than it looks. The attempt I made forget to factor in the fact that each number can only be picked once. That constraint alone makes it impossible to solve in one pass.

Comment: It's quite a brain teaser. At this point, the best idea I have requires evaluating at worst ~10^32 cases. I wonder how to cut that number down to something reasonable.

Comment: I think another way to approach the problem is to partition the 50 numbers into sublists, you can only arrange 50 numbers so many ways to have at least at least a difference of 16 between consecutive nums

Comment: How random does the list need to be? There are a finite number of sequences that fulfill your criteria; does every sequence need to have the same probability of being produced as an output (ie., perfectly random)? Can the algorithm eliminate some (or even most) of the possible candidates? I think there may be efficient algorithms that are non-deterministic but only consider a very limited subset of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following approach. Start with a shuffled list. For each pair, if the distance is less than 15 rotate the remaining numbers.

```
import random

def get_shuffled_list(length):
    output = range(1, length+1)
    i = 0
    sanity = 0

    while i < length and sanity == 0:
        random.shuffle(output)
        for i in range(1, length):
            sanity = length - i + 1

            while abs(output[i-1] - output[i]) <= 15 and sanity:
                output.append(output[i])
                del output[i]
                sanity -= 1

            if sanity == 0:
                break

    return output

print get_shuffled_list(50)
```

Giving the following type of output:

```
[1, 38, 3, 33, 16, 43, 10, 41, 9, 35, 4, 50, 29, 8, 44, 28, 5, 32, 14, 40, 21, 47, 25, 48, 30, 12, 34, 18, 42, 15, 36, 13, 31, 2, 24, 7, 23, 39, 22, 6, 26, 49, 27, 11, 45, 19, 46, 17, 37, 20]
```

The issue comes at the end if you fail to have any remaining numbers that satisfy the criteria, in which case, start again. For a test of 10,000 shuffles, the worst case I managed was 196 attempts. Not ideal but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try somethings like this:

- Start with an initial value for `last`. 
  This value should be a string (`'start'`).
- Loop for however many times you need:

  - Check if `last == 'start'`.
  - If it is, add a random number to the list.
  - If it isn’t, create a random number.

    - Until `abs(number - last)` is less than 15, create a new random number.
    - Add the number to the list.
  - Set `last` to the last element of the list.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to put your initialization inside the loop. In any case, this will pick duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**edit: does not answer the question, as it CAN and WILL pick some numbers several times.** Leaving it around in case this variant is of use to someone else.

The algorithm you use, and the one suggested by JF share an interesting flaw: there is no limit to the time they take. If you are really unlucky, the function could not return before the end of the universe.

Here is one that will execute in bound time, namely `O(n)`:

```
import random

def spaced_randoms(min_val, max_val, number, space):
    if max_val - min_val <= 2 * space:
        raise ValueError('interval not large enough for space')

    last = random.randint(min_val, max_val)
    result = [last]
    for _ in range(number - 1):
        skip_low = max(0, min(space, last - min_val))
        skip_high = max(0, min(space, max_val - last))
        value = random.randint(min_val + skip_low, max_val - skip_high - 1)

        last = value - skip_low if value < last else value + skip_high + 1
        result.append(last)

    return result

>>> print(spaced_randoms(0, 50, 50, 15))
[35, 10, 44, 26, 47, 22, 49, 29, 3, 28, 44, 17, 40, 3, 39, 7, 48, 22, 41, 5, 21, 4, 32, 9, 34, 3, 46, 3, 20, 38, 10, 49, 32, 16, 38, 5, 26, 45, 26, 49, 13, 44, 1, 30, 12, 30, 0, 46, 15, 42]
```

The idea is simple : we reduce the possible interval for the new number to account for forbidden values. The we remap the result. For instance, assuming for 15 space at some point `last == 32`, then:

- we pick a number between 15 and 34.
- if picked number is in [15 to 31], we remap to [0 to 16]
- if picked number is in [32 to 34], we remap to [48 to 50]

Comment: The OP also would like each number used only once.

Answer (score 0):

Well, something along the line, in pseudocode

```
sampled = []

n = 50

x = 15

curr = n + x + 1

for k in range(1, 1000):

    # build exclusion range tuple, where you cannot sample,
    # say for calc_ex_range(50, 15, 27) it should return
    # (12, 42)
    exclude_range = calc_ex_range(n, x, curr)

    # build new sampling array, given the exclusion range
    # result should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50]
    sampling_array = calc_sarray(n, exclude_range)

    # remove already sampled numbers from sampling array
    sampling_array = filter_sarray(sampling_array[:], sampled)
    if len(sampling_array) == 0:
        break

    # sample one item from the array
    curr = random.sample(sampling_array, 1)

    sampled.append(curr)
```

Complexity would be O(N^2), I guess, but it always finishes

UPDATE

In order to sample number once, filter out sampled array

Comment: Actually, like my own answer, this will pick the same number several times, failing to meet the goal of the question.

Comment: @spectras Aha! Shall read requirements more carefully. See edited answer

Comment: That's what I thought as well at first, unfortunately once modified in this way, the algorithm has a high chance of failing. For example: imagine you have chosen 48 numbers alright, but the last tow unchosen numbers are 49 and 50 (or any two numbers that are within 15 of each other).

Comment: @spectras well, I think that would be tough to prove that starting with ANY number in sequence you'll always end up selecting ALL elements (of course, satisfying all conditions)

Answer (score 0):

After the other answer that failed to meet the "each item must appear exactly once" requirement, here are some thoughts:

If I call *spacing* the minimum absolute difference between two consecutive numbers, then:

- Selecting the beginning of the array is easy. You can do that with Severin Pappadeux's code.
- Once you are left with 2 * *spacing* unchosen items, you must switch algorithms.
- The problem of choosing the last items seems to be P-complete.

Unfortunately I am not good enough at algorithm theory to build a formal proof. Also, maybe it's just I failed to find a better way. But at this point I don't see any way but implementing picking of the last items as a graph search.

As interesting as this is, however, I cannot afford more time on it. But if you come back and answer your own question I'll love reading it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to arbitrarily exclude many permutations that fit your criteria, you can quite easily create an algorithm for generating permutations that will work.

The simplest example I can think of is the following:

- Partition the range `{1,50}` into 10 sub-ranges of five numbers: `{1,5},{6,10},{11,15}...`.
- Pick a sequence of these sub-ranges such that for any two sub-ranges next to each other, the closest elements are at least 15 apart. The simplest way to do this is to pick every fourth sub-range: `{1,5},{21,25},{41,45},{11,15}...`
- The output sequence starts with one randomly-chosen number from each range: `3,22,41,15...`
- Continue picking numbers from the sub-ranges in order until you've picked all 5 numbers from each sub-range (i.e. until you've picked every number in the full range from 0 to 50): `3,22,41,15...1,24,42,14...4,21...`

You can do simple variations of this by picking different sub-range sizes (e.g. `15` or `7`, although these introduce an additional complication of not evenly partitioning the original range). Or you can randomly transpose  elements of the output sequence (or otherwise mutate the sequence) following the rule that you can never invalidate the sequence (i.e. you cannot introduce a pairing of elements that are less than 15 apart). You could also make the ordering of sub-ranges quasi-random, or change the ordering on ach iteration through the sub-ranges.

Even with these variations, this obviously won't be a fully random selection of any possible valid permutation. But in practice, I expect there's a good chance that that won't matter.

Answer (score -1):

How about this? I use randint to easily get an integer within the range you require:

```
import random

my_list = []
# This number should not be within 15 units from each
# new random integer:
previous = random.randint(1, 50)

# Loop until my_list' length is 50; see at the bottom
while True:
    # Get a new random integer from 1 to 50
    rand_int = random.randint(1, 50)

    # If the new integer is NOT at a range within 15 of the previous number,
    # append to the list; otherwise skip and try again
    if not rand_int - 15 < previous < rand_int + 15:
        my_list.append(rand_int)
        # This new integer becomes the new previous
        previous = rand_int

    if len(my_list) >= 50:
        # Break from the loop and print the new list
        break

print(my_list)
```

Comment: This picks duplicates.